# What tense is "acknowledge" in "provided he acknowledge"?

Tags: verbs, tenses

The [Texas Constitution](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Docs/CN/htm/CN.1.htm) has a sentence that ends with the phrase "provided he acknowledge the existence of a Supreme Being." What tense is the verb "acknowledge" in here?

Comment: it's present tense, subjunctive mood.

Comment: Present tense, subjunctive mood, stupid sense.  This is the whole provision supposedly barring religious tests for office: "No religious test shall ever be required as a qualification to any office, or public trust, in this State; nor shall any one be excluded from holding office on account of his religious sentiments, provided he acknowledge the existence of a Supreme Being."  No religious test but this one.  It's void per the Supreme Court.  When can we give that state back to Mexico?

Comment: @deadrat Hey hey hey! I live in that state ;). And never - you'd have to give Texas back to itself, seeing as it was its own nation.

Comment: @deadrat Texas is home to some good schools. There used to be this conference that I would speak at every year called CombinaTexas (combinatorics in the American southwest!) but it didn't happen this year. I thought I might have overheard somebody denying the existence of a supreme being there, so that could explain it.

Comment: What!? The Texas Constitution is ***my go-to reference*** for proper English usage.

Comment: **When can we give that state back to Mexico?**  Doesn't Mexico have enough problems as it is?

Comment: @MillieSmith Yes, Texas was the only independent nation to become part of the US.  (Hawaii might be considered a second.)  Whatever heed the rest of the country owes to the Texas founding myths expired on 2/1/65.  That's 1865.

Comment: @MattSamuel I'll agree to keep Austin, but that's it.

Comment: @Cargill Hmm.  Good point.  But Mexico should have the right of first refusal.

Comment: @deadrat If you mean Texas' secession, that was 2/1/1861, wasn't it?

Comment: @BrianDonovan Yeah, my bad.  Fat-fingered my own punchline.  I'll give 'em the benefit of the doubt.  Let's date that from 6/19/1865.

Comment: Fascinating. Section 22—"Treason against the State shall consist only in levying war against it, or adhering to its enemies, giving them aid and comfort; and no person shall be convicted of treason except on the testimony of two witnesses to the same overt act, or on confession in open court."—suggests that you can be convicted of treason against the state of Texas if you "adhere to its enemies." The obvious question is, Who in Texas decides who the enemies of Texas are and what adhering to them consists of?

Comment: @deadrat In the eyes of Californians, the Bear Republic was actually independent of Mexico for a time before being 'conquered' by the U.S. 
Legally speaking, it was relinquished by Mexico, so some say it was never actually an independent republic.  But... the bear flag.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Republic

Comment: @JoshB The so-called "Bear Republic" was never independent of Mexico.  A few malcontents declared a republic in June 1846 in an area north of San Francisco, established no governmental authority, and disbanded three weeks later at the arrival of the US military.  No other country recognized them.  Heck, nobody in what is now Los Angeles ever heard of them.  The clowns who occupied that building in a wildlife refuge in Oregon controlled more for a longer time.

Comment: Agreed - that's why I mentioned "it was never actually an independent republic."

Comment: @SvenYargs The definition of treason in the Texas Constitution is copied, mutatis mutandis, from the United States Constitution (Article III, Section 3).

Comment: @bof: Right; but the United States is a nation, and therefore its enemies in the first instance are hostile nations and their agents, foreign and domestic. It seems to me that the Constitution's understanding of treason doesn't translate well to the state level. After all, New York may be both a rival to Texas and hostile to it. If my neighborhood block association adopted a bylaw about "treason against the neighborhood" and defined it, in part, as "adhering to the enemies of the Ocean View Neighborhood," I would wonder who decides who the enemies are and what "adhering" to them means.

Comment: @deadrat Actually the [Vermont Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermont_Republic) was the first independent nation to join the United States.

Answer (score 2):

As sumelic points out in a comment above, the word *acknowledge* in the phrase "provided he acknowledge the existence of a Supreme Being" is a subjunctive, and the tense is present.

The sense of the phrase is

> if he satisfies the prerequisite of recognizing and affirming the existence of a Supreme Being.

The full provision that the OP quotes from is this:

> Sec. 4.  RELIGIOUS TESTS.  No religious test shall ever be required as a qualification to any office, or public trust, in this State; nor shall any one be excluded from holding office on account of his religious sentiments, provided he acknowledge the existence of a Supreme Being.

(A constitutional literalist might observe that this provision explicitly applies only to "any one" who is male—cf. "his religious sentiments"—but whether that is because the Texas constitution deems only (religious) men fit for office or because it envisions different standards for male nonbelievers and female nonbelievers is a matter not addressed by the plain terms of the provision.)

Of course, requiring prospective officeholders to make any such acknowledgment in order to qualify for state office or public trust is clearly a discriminatory religious test—notwithstanding the framers' attempt to cast the test as neutral toward individual religions and hostile only toward irreligion (which in any event puts the framers in the highly dubious position of asserting that disqualifying candidates for not being religious is not a "religious test" as that term is understood in U.S. constitutional law). [All-Father Odin](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin) may be the most deep-minded of the Æsir, but he is by no means a Supreme Being—and indeed doesn't rate a capital H when referred to by pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'provided' appears six times in the [first article of the Texas Constitution, as published on the state's website](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Docs/CN/htm/CN.1.htm).

The first four usages are in the sense of 'given that,' or "[on the condition that](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/provided)." In this particular document, each of these four usages happens also to occur when the writer is countering the previous phrase, eg. "Provided, however,[...]." The other two uses later on are both 'as provided by,' meaning "as made available by." (dictionary.com)

The sentence in question concerns a possible prerequisite for holding office:
"*No religious test shall ever be required as a qualification to any office, or public trust, in this State; nor shall any one be excluded from holding office on account of his religious sentiments, provided he acknowledge the existence of a Supreme Being.*"

"Nor shall anyone be excluded" has the same meaning as "no one will be excluded." As mentioned above, 'provided' is used here to connect the condition of an aspiring politician, which may exist now or in the future, that is necessary for the future office-holding to occur. Therefore the relevant phrase could be understood as "no one will be excluded, given that she also will acknowledge...."

The verb 'acknowledge' in this sense is future conditional, not subjunctive, as it describes a condition in the future that is necessary for another event to then occur.